# How to write tests for time based contracts?

Tags: solidity, testing, ethers.js, timestamp, hardhat

I have a function that requires 7 days to pass from the time of an event (lockTime) before the rest of it will execute:

```
function resetGame () public onlyOwner {
    require (block.timestamp >= lockTime + 7 days);
    _;
}
```

how could I write a test using JS and chai to test that when 7 days pass, the function works as intended?

(p.s. I am using Hardhart and ethers.js)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `evm_increaseTime` rpc available in Hardhat Network ([docs](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/reference/#evm-increasetime)).

```
await hre.ethers.provider.send('evm_increaseTime', [7 * 24 * 60 * 60]);
```